# Is there a shortcut key to comment multiple lines in matlab editor

Tags: matlab, editor

Is there a shortcut to comment multiple lines in matlab. If there isn't can I create one?

Comment: What OS are you working on? Some shortcuts differ slightly between systems.

Comment: ...& Ctrl+T to un-comment.

Comment: OP was looking for a way to comment multiple lines... not how to uncomment.  I think your shortcut may still be relevant as a comment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The comment shortcut is <kbd>CTRL+R</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>CTRL+/</kbd> on Unix systems (not sure about OS X). To comment multiple lines you'd have to highlight them using the mouse or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

In any case this can be customized via Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

Comment: to add a little bit to that, you don't even have to select the full line(s) ... any line partially selected will get commented.

Comment: And Ctrl-T to uncomment.

Comment: In my case it's still `Ctrl+R`, even though I'm using Ubuntu (which _is_ a UNIX system).

Comment: uncomment on macOS by default is `alt+command+/`

Answer (score 11):

In Octave, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to comment and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to un-comment.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to comment code.
Then, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to un-comment.